# Image transfering with Java Socket

Tags: java, image, sockets, transfer

i have school assigment and im trying to achieve transfer screenshots from client to server with java. Actually, i feel like im pretty close to it cause it works fine when i run both client and server on the same computer but as you know i need to do it from different computers. The problem is when i tried to do that, there is a corrupted image. I think there is something wrong with read or write methods. Can you please help me?

Client:

```
InetAddress host = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        Socket socket = null;
        while(true) {
        try {
            
            Robot r = new Robot();
            socket = new Socket(host.getHostAddress(), 9876);
            
            Rectangle capture = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()); 
            
            BufferedImage image = r.createScreenCapture(capture); 
            
            ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
            
            ImageIO.write(image,"jpg",baos);
            
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()); 
            
            BufferedInputStream reader = new BufferedInputStream(bais);
            
        
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            
            byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;
            while((bytesRead = reader.read(buffer))!=-1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
        
            
                
            reader.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();

            Thread.sleep(500);
            
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

Server:

```
server = new ServerSocket(port);
        
        
        while(true) {
            
        Socket socket = server.accept();
        
        BufferedInputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        
        int nRead;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        while((nRead = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length))!= -1) {
            baos.write(buffer);
        }
        
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()));
        
        if(frame==null){
                Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
                frame=new JFrame();
                frame.setSize(screenSize.width, screenSize.height);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                
                if(frame.getHeight()!=image.getHeight() || frame.getWidth()!=image.getWidth()) {
                    Image resizedImage = image.getScaledInstance(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    label=new JLabel();
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage));
                    frame.getContentPane().add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }else {
                    label=new JLabel();
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                    frame.getContentPane().add(label,BorderLayout.CENTER);
                    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                    frame.pack();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                }
    
           }else {
               if(frame.getHeight()!=image.getHeight() || frame.getWidth()!=image.getWidth()) {
                    Image resizedImage = image.getScaledInstance(frame.getWidth(), frame.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(resizedImage));
                }else {
                    label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                }
               
           }
        
    }
```

[This is how it looks like when i get the image from client](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHXWv.jpg)
Thanks.

Comment: If image is arrived on other side and is recognizable then you got your network transfer part right.   Possible causes of quality loss would be:   capture resolution,   compression rations if applicable and scaling  on the display side

Comment: If it worked when on the same computer,  I see nothing that would cause image problems on another computer.

Comment: I got some pixels from client but its not recognizable at all. I also believe the network transfer part right. I will try to write to disk whenever it writes and reads on the socket.

Comment: Why don't you show us what the image looks like?

Comment: You do have at least one bug here: `baos.write(buffer);` should be `baos.write(buffer, 0, nRead);`

Comment: that bug solved my whole problem. incredible. thanks a lot..